# Excel, XML and XSD

Tags: xml, excel, automation, xsd

I have been trying to get this to work for several hours now and feel like I didn't even get close to anything.

I have a Software for creating Invoices that allows me to export the invoice data into Excel. Now I am trying to get it to be a working xml file to import it into the accounting software, but I am not at all good at XML and that may be a vast understatement. I've seen people do it and watched a lot of guides but just can't manage to apply it to my case.

Here's what I got:
Excel
https://www.dropbox.com/s/irabh2zjr98azyr/Rechnungen.xlsx

Really would appreciate your help and maybe a short walkthrough of how you did it, as I am trying to learn it for the next time.

Thanks in advance.

Zanda

Comment: you would need to know what format the XML needs to be in

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, how can i find out? I'm using the camt.054 format in my Accounting software already (from bank), if that helps in any way.

Comment: so i tried importing a normal XML file and it gives me an error message saying I Need a ebXML file.

Comment: Ask the provider of your accounting software for an API which describes how XML must look like to be a "working xml file to import it into the accounting software". Maybe that API also provides import of Excel files.